# Make copies of database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, while-loop, copy, database-restore

I have a database with all tables needed, on which is perfectly usable. But for test purposes, I need to make copies of the database for, lets say 100 times. (My application will loop on each database to execute some scripts).

The databases generated should bear different names of course. To use `Backup/Restore` or even `Detach/Copy/Attach` a 100 times is not do-able. So I would like to know if there's a script which can loop to copy/restore a database several times on different names?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you claim that `backup / restore` isn't possible? That's probably the most efficient and simplest solution to this challenge!

Comment: I'm not saying its not possible, but imagine doing this a 100-200 times?! That would take a full day..

Comment: Just script it out - you can easily create the `BACKUP DATABASE ...` and the `RESTORE ...` as script and just let it run unattended .....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, that's what I tried, and it works fine. I've added the solution I found as answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found something that's working for me, by simple **WHILE LOOP**;

```
DECLARE @index int
DECLARE @dbName varchar(25)
declare @HRNET varchar(200)
declare @HRNET_LOG varchar(200) 
declare @sql varchar(2000)
SET @index = 5

WHILE (@index < 200)
BEGIN

-- Construct db name and corresponding files name
SET @dbName = 'BDName' + Right('0000' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @index), 4) 
set @MDF = '''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\' + @dbName + '.mdf'''
SET @LDF = '''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\' + @dbName + '_1.ldf'''

-- Restore db from backup bak file
SELECT @sql = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @dbName + '
FROM  DISK = ''C:\DB Backup\DBName1919.bak'' 
WITH  FILE = 1,   
MOVE ''WEEKLY_UK_CO_E_REPORTING_Data'' TO ' +  @MDF + ',  
MOVE ''WEEKLY_UK_CO_E_REPORTING_Log'' TO ' + @LDF + 
', NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10'  

exec(@sql)  


SET @index = @index + 1 

END
GO
```

To retrieve the backup path location (MDF & LDF), just run the following;

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = N'C:\DB Backup\DBName1919.bak'
```